# Does an ! before a condition change its execution?

Tags: java

For the condition
while (!(cChoice=='Q'||cChoice=='q')), an input of Q or q will cause the program to exit. Does the position of the ! cause this to happen? If so, can you explain why? I am just learning Java, so please go easy on me.

Comment: A ! boolean-negates the meaning of the expression inside. What the if is doing or not is hard to tell if you dont show us. But yes, if you negate an expression it does the opposite of what it does before (kind of).

Answer (score 1):

Well since the negation applies to the whole expression,

```
(!(cChoice=='Q'||cChoice=='q'))
```

evaluates to

```
!cChoice=='Q' && !cChoice=='q'
```

using boolean algebra:

(A+B)' = A' . B'

So if input choice is either of those the program will quit. It's not specific to java or any language.

Answer (score 1):

To help understand why this conditional behaves as it does, we can break it down.

First, the inner block, `cChoice == 'Q' || cChoice == 'q'` will give a result of `True` if input is 'Q' **or** 'q'.

Next, adding an `!` outside of this block will **negate** the result. So, in english, we can read this as:

`while NOT(input is 'Q' or 'q'), execute`

or... while we don't receive 'Q' or 'q' as input, execute.

Answer (score 0):

For the statement :
    while(cChoice=='Q'||cChoice=='q')
an input of Q or q will set this the condition as true. Hence the code inside while loop will run. But when you add the "!"(i.e., **not**) before the condition, the condition is now !(true), which means "not" true and hence **false**. So the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly true:

```
not male(Jeff) or not female(Jeff)
```

Clearly false:

```
not (male(Jeff) or female(Jeff))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to understand this, is just to replace ! with ==false.

```
(!(cChoice=='Q'||cChoice=='q'))
```

is the same as

```
((cChoice=='Q'||cChoice=='q')==false)
```